# Using transactions on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my Firebase project. I am trying to add a reaction button to it, so what I did is everytime a user presses love/like button, the firebase node which has "ReactingUser" as node, it will add the userID as Key and "1" as value. Also, the total number of reactions on the post is denoted by "TotalReactions" node which will count the total number of children of "ReactingUser" and set the value accordingly. My question is that, what if two user press it at the same time, I know it will cause collision and I may face problem because my data is depended on that "TotalReactions" node. Can anyone tell me how can I use transactions on my database so that I won't have collision problem? I tried going through other tutorials, but none of them clarify me. This is how my code for reaction button looks like:

```
reactionUserDatabase.child(uniqueKey).child("ReactingUser").child(currentUserID).setValue("1").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            reactionUserDatabase.child(uniqueKey).child("ReactingUser").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String totalVotes = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    reactionUserDatabase.child(uniqueKey).child("TotalReactions").setValue(totalVotes).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Now how can I implement the data transactions to prevent collision? Or am I going a good go and it won't effect ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use transactions:

```
reactionUserDatabase.child(uniqueKey).child("ReactingUser").child(currentUserID).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        String stringTotalVotes = mutableData.getValue(String.class);
        int totalVotes = Integer.valueOf(stringTotalVotes);

        if (totalVotes == null) {
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        if (totalVotes != null) {
            totalVotes = totalVotes - 1;
        } else {
            totalVotes = totalVotes + 1;
        }

        mutableData.setValue(String.valueOf(totalVotes));
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

As you see, this code is using the String class but I strongly recommend you to set the value of your `currentUserID` field as an `int` and not as a String.